# Are isomorphisms automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a set $X$ and two group operations on the set $\oplus,+$. If they are isomorphic, does it follow that $\oplus=+$?

I am unable to think of counter-examples, and this makes sense to me at an intuitive level because "isomorphism" means something in my head like "the operations are the same, just with a different set." However, I'm unable to prove it using the standard definition of $f(x\oplus y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: "If they are isomorphic"...could you be more precise?

Comment: @julien: there exists an invertible $f$ where $f(x\oplus y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Comment: I don't think so. You could give the set $\{a,b\}$ a group structure in two different ways, one in which $a$ is the identity, and the other with $b$ the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $G$ be a nontrivial group under the operation $\bullet$ and let $f:G\to G$ be a permutation of its elements (which we don't regard as a homomorphism). Define $\circ$ on $G$ by $f(a\circ b)=f(a)\bullet f(b)$.

Then $(G,\circ)\cong(G,\bullet)$ but $\circ,\bullet$ needn't be the same operation. Essentially this means we can make the underlying set of $G$ into the group $G$ in many different ways by relabelling its elements.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? So if $a, b \in G$, what is $a \circ b$? (I don't mean what is $f(a\circ b)$?)

Comment: @amWhy: $a\circ b=f^{-1}(f(a)\bullet f(b))$. For a concrete example, pick $G=\{0,1\}$, and there are two ways to put the unique group-of-order-2 structure on this set: one in which $0$ is the identity under $\circ$, and the other in which $1$ is the identity under $\bullet$. (I now see this example was given by Derek. It is the smallest, after all.)

Comment: Okay...I get what you're saying...Wasn't trying to nitpick! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $G=\mathbb R$ to be the set of real numbers. Let $+: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the usual addition operation, and let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the bijective function defined by $f(a):=a^3$. Now, define $\oplus: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ to be the operation defined by $$a\oplus b:=f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b))=(a^3+b^3)^{1/3}.$$ You can check that $(\mathbb R,+)$ and $(\mathbb R,\oplus)$ are both groups, moreover $f:(\mathbb R,\oplus)\rightarrow (\mathbb R,+)$ is automatically an isomorphism of groups; but $+$ and $\oplus$ are different as operations.